# Stability condition for AdS background (when gravity coupled to matter fields)

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, stability, supergravity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

In finding the stability condition for AdS background (when gravity coupled to matter fields), why the conserved energy should be positive?